# Object reference not set to an instance of an object While trying to Update data with the help of database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, project-management

I am creating a Books website i have made an books page in which i have given edit books page link when i click on that link a update form should open based on that books id from the database and that update form should be filled with pre entered details from the database.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WEbApp
{
    public partial class Edit_Books : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="ConnectionString";Integrated Security=True");
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                con.Close();
            }
            con.Open();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["bkid"].ToString());

            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Books where bkid="+id+"";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                Textbox1.Text = dr["book_name"].ToString();
                Textbox2.Text = dr["book_author"].ToString();
                Textbox3.Text = dr["book_publication"].ToString();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the upper code I get an error on this line:

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["bkid"].ToString());
```

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `Request.QueryString` doesn't contain an entry for`bkid` ?

Change the code to this:

```
var bkId = Request.QueryString["bkid"];
int id = Convert.ToInt32(bkId.ToString());
```

Check the value of bkId with your debugger - I suspect it will be `null`.

Comment: When the books page open it shows all books data and a update button when i click on the update button it takes the id of that book and redirects user to the edit book page. But in this case everything goes until the click when i click on the button it shows the id in the link in search bar but page shows an error.

Comment: Surely changing `int id` to `int? id` would be better in this case?

Comment: The problem is that `bkId` is null.  `id` will never be assigned because `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception.

Comment: tried replacing the code still getting the same error.  I am referring this video : https://youtu.be/yM9Y7NMxC28 i wanna do the same he is doing to edit the books. Please take a look at the video and tell me what to do.

Comment: If you have seen the video can you help me please?

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger?  What is the value of bkId after stepping over the line?

Comment: I added you code instead of this int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["bkid"].ToString()); and now its showing this error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
bkId was null.

Comment: Anyone can help me with the probllem?

Comment: We have proved that my answer is correct.  The problem is not in this code, it's in the code that posts back to this code.